# integer solutions of $ (n!+1)=m^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider $4!=24$, if you add one you get $25=5^2$. The same occurs with $5! = 120 = 11^2 - 1$, and $7! = 5040 = 71^2 - 1$. Are there other solutions of the equation $n!+1 = m^2$?

I verified that no other solution exists with $m<10^9$. Does the problem has already been studied? Is there a demonstration that no other solution exists?

Greetings.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem

Comment: It's probably discussed in Guy, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory (I don't have the book at hand, so cannot check). 

Comment: You might enjoy this one, $$ $$
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16341/on-polynomials-dividing-exponentials/ 
$$ $$
Gerry, it is in Guy, section D25, page 193 in the second edition. About 8 references. $$ $$ 